# URL Parsing into Database

Tags: php, database, parsing, url, extract

I have a form in which users can input a URL. Now obviously they some will put in www.example.com/path or example.com/path or http://www.example.com/path or even http://example.com/path.

What I want to do is to extract the whole URL host and path ect.. and put it in a standard form into my database. So no matter how it is formatted in the input they all have the same formatting in the database.

so the inputs go to outputs like below

```
www.example.com/path -> http://www.example.com/path
example.com/path -> http://www.example.com/path
http://www.example.com/path -> http://www.example.com/path
http://example.com/path ->http://www.example.com/path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex for the URL's then use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) when validating it and specify PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE to make it into an array of the values in the matches. Then manipulate it to a string that satisfies your format.

Comment: Sorry but am really amateur at PHP so have no idea how to do any of that

Comment: Using regular expressions means you're chopping a code into smaller pieces and categorizing them so you can modify or get the value of each piece. For example, a number consists of digits and a digit consists of numbers 0 to 9.

function valid_number(

 $digit="(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)";
 if(preg_match("$digit*"){
  return 1;
 }
 return 0;

}

The symbol '|' separates the options for the digit and the symbol '*' says there can be zero or more of them.

The values will be put into an array so that you can manipulate them the way you want. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

Find below example:

```
function updateUrl($url) {  
    if (strpos($url, '://')=== false && strpos($url, 'www.')=== false) {
        $url = 'http://www.' . $url;
    }
    else if(strpos($url, '://')=== false) {
        $url = 'http://' . $url;
    }
    else if(strpos($url, 'www.')=== false) {
        $url = str_replace('http://','http://www.',$url);
    }
    else {
        $url = $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
$url = "http://example.com/path";
echo updateUrl($url);
```